# Typo3 `jh_opengraphprotocol` extension and custom og:image tag

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, tt-news

I have a question, does anybody know how to make `jh_opengraphprotocol` extension show first image from `tt_news` appear as `<meta property="og:image" ...>`?

I have tried few things and now I'm stuck at passing a custom image value to that extension.

**Getting first image from currently show tt_news (TypoScript Setup):**

```
lib.tt_news_image = CONTENT
lib.tt_news_image {
  stdWrap.if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_ttnews|tt_news
  table = tt_news
  select {
    pidInList = 20
    recursive = 2
    where = CHAR_LENGTH(image) > 0

    andWhere.cObject = TEXT
    andWhere.cObject {
      data = GP:tx_ttnews|tt_news
      intval = 1
      wrap = uid = |
    }

  }
  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
    field = image
    split {
      token = ,
      cObjNum = 1
      max = 1
      1.cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
      1.cObject {
        file {
          import = uploads/pics/
          import.current = 1
          width = 200m
          height = 200m
        }
        stdWrap.wrap = {TSFE:baseUrl}|
        stdWrap.insertData = 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine. When showing this value in FE I get a nice URL to resized file - GREAT!

Now I have hoped to pass that value to the extension and here a have met some problems. Few tries below...

***#1*** `plugin.tx_jhopengraphprotocol.image = lib.tt_news_image`

**Fail** - nothing happens because `plugin.tx_jhopengraphprotocol.image` is a constant

***#2*** 
After some digging I found that plugin is loading a `USER` object into `page.669` like below:

```
config.htmlTag_setParams := appendString(xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#")

includeLibs.tx_jhopengraphprotocol = EXT:jh_opengraphprotocol/Classes/Service/OgRendererService.php
temp.tx_jhopengraphprotocol = USER
temp.tx_jhopengraphprotocol {
    userFunc = Heilmann\JhOpengraphprotocol\Service\OgRendererService->main
    type = {$plugin.tx_jhopengraphprotocol.type}
    image = {$plugin.tx_jhopengraphprotocol.image}
    sitename = {$plugin.tx_jhopengraphprotocol.sitename}
    description = {$plugin.tx_jhopengraphprotocol.description}
}
page.669 < temp.tx_jhopengraphprotocol
```

So I have tried `page.669.image = lib.tt_news_image` this was a ...

**FAIL** I got `<meta property="og:image" content="http://domainname/lib.tt_news_image"/>`

Can anyone guide me how to load the `lib.tt_news_image` value into the `page.669.image` properly? I think this is somehow related to the `USER` type, parameters (`image`, `type`, ...) are not interpreted by the Typo engine, but I have no clue how to get over it.

My general problem is to load that first image path to `og:image` meta tag, so any other solutions (not fixing this code or anything are very welcome).

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using plugin.tx_jhopengraphprotocol.image = lib.tt_news_image or plugin.tx_jhopengraphprotocol.image < lib.tt_news_image ?

Comment: @JozefSpisiak none of those was working for me